# Are there any powers that don't actually work on Multiplayer? Or is it a glitch?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

While playing Mass Effect 3 on PS3 (I have a copy for PC too), I noticed that Adrenaline rush and Cloak don't really work for me on MP.

Comment: Cloak works just fine for me on multiplayer.  Note that its not supposed to make you totally invisible, but it does make it so the enemies take longer to acquire you as a target.

Comment: Don't really work as in they actually have no effect or they don't seem to help somehow? I know Cloak works for a fact and I'm sure ADrenaline works normally unless you found a rare glitch

Comment: Cloak works, but it's main effect is not hiding you - if you fire a weapon from cloaked it does a _lot_ more damage. With a decent sniper rifle, a headshot bonus and cloak you can kill almost anything in a single headshot.

Answer (score 3):

Adrenaline Rush [gives you the stats boost despite it not slowing time](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-Multiplayer-Discussion-/Adrenaline-Rush--9300911-1.html), probably because that would be difficult to do in multiplayer:

> [I]t doesn't slow down time in MP; it just gives you a boost in damage+protection and weapon stability.

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55159/6066) to another question seems to indicate that cloaking works.  Can you be more specific about your problem?

**Edit:** I agree with yx. that you're probably just expecting the wrong thing here; as he says, Cloak just makes you harder to target, not impossible to target.

Comment: Every kind of enemy can target me even when I'm cloaked, even when standing still. I'm not sure about AR but it seems I do less damage with AR.

Comment: @Dylan Ip, cloak isn't supposed to make you totally unnoticable, the same way you can still see Geth hunters despite them cloaking.  It just makes you harder to notice/target so you can run around a bit easier.